# Reproduce a graph with graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I want to reproduce an specific figure I saw on a book using graphviz. This is the graph in the book: [image: I want this]

But using the following `.dot`:

```
    digraph rf{
    rankdir=LR;
    graph[size="5,5",ratio=fill, overlap=false];
    //node[height="2", width="2", fontsize="50"];
    //edge[penwidth="4", fontsize="50"]
    <a>[color=red];
    <b>[color=red];
    <s>[color=purple];
    <t>[color=purple];
    <s>-><a>[label="500/0"]
    <s>-><b>[label="500/0"]
    <a>-><b>[label="1/0"]
    <a>-><t>[label="500/0"]
    <b>-><t>[label="500/0"]
}
```

I get this:

[image: I don't want this]

Notice how it's really big and kind of expanded, also the labels sare overlapped with the edges.

I'd like to get a very similar graph to the one in the book.

The command I use to plot this:

```
circo -Tpng errornet2.dot -oerrornet2.png
```

Hope I can get some help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `dot` engine instead of circo and `constraint=false`on one edge you are near there

```
digraph rf{
    rankdir=LR;
    graph[size="5,5",ratio=fill, overlap=false];
    node[height="2", width="2", fontsize="50"];
    edge[penwidth="4", fontsize="50"]
    <a>[color=red];
    <b>[color=red];
    <s>[color=purple];
    <t>[color=purple];
    <s>-><a>[label="500/0"]
    <s>-><b>[label="500/0"]
    <a>-><b>[label="1/0" constraint=false]
    <a>-><t>[label="500/0"]
    <b>-><t>[label="500/0"]
}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but why did you decide to use `constraint` on that specific edge?

Comment: What difference do you notice if you omit the constraint?